# Sorting and selecting from 3 CSV files

Tags: sql, vba, csv, ms-access

Every month I receive a data dump of several CSV files. Some of the files exceed the Microsoft Excel maximum rows, but I was able to use an ADODB recordset and connection to select and sort the files and only load the values I need. I can get it to work for two files, but in one case, I need it to go to three files, and there is the problem.

The following code works for two files:

```
Dim cnD As New ADODB.Connection
cnD.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
cnD.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + fullFolder + ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;" + _
        "FMT=Delimited(,)"""
cnD.Open
Dim rsD As New ADODB.Recordset
rsD.ActiveConnection = cnD
rsD.Source = "SELECT Data.id AS HapDataId, Data.createtimestamp, " + _
                    "Data.lastmodified, Goals.* " + _
        "FROM HAPData.csv AS Data " + _
            "INNER JOIN HAPGoals.csv AS Goals ON Data.Id = Goals.hapid " + _
        "WHERE Format(Data.createtimestamp, " + """" + "yyyy-MM-dd" + """" + ") >= " + _
                    "Format(#" + startDateStr + "#, " + """" + "yyyy-MM-dd" + """" + ") OR " + _
                "Format(Data.lastmodified, " + """" + "yyyy-MM-dd" + """" + ") >= " + _
                    "Format(#" + startDateStr + "#, " + """" + "yyyy-MM-dd" + """" + ") " + _
        "ORDER BY Data.id, Data.lastmodified, Data.createtimestamp, Goals.id "
rsD.Open
```

and generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT Data.id AS HapDataId, Data.createtimestamp, Data.lastmodified, Goals.* 
FROM HAPData.csv AS Data INNER JOIN HAPGoals.csv AS Goals ON Data.id = Goals.hapid 
WHERE Format(Data.createtimestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd") >= Format(#7/1/2019#, "yyyy-MM-dd") OR 
    Format(Data.lastmodified, "yyyy-MM-dd") >= Format(#7/1/2019#, "yyyy-MM-dd") 
ORDER BY Data.id, Data.lastmodified, Data.createtimestamp, Goals.id
```

If I modify it to add the third file, I get the following SQL:

```
SELECT Data.id AS HapDataId, Data.createtimestamp, Data.lastmodified, Goals.*, Actions.* 
FROM HAPData.csv AS Data INNER JOIN HAPGoals.csv AS Goals ON Data.id = Goals.hapid 
    INNER JOIN HAPActionSteps.csv AS Actions ON Goals.id = Actions.goalid 
WHERE Format(Data.createtimestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd") >= Format(#7/1/2019#, "yyyy-MM-dd") OR 
    Format(Data.lastmodified, "yyyy-MM-dd") >= Format(#7/1/2019#, "yyyy-MM-dd") 
ORDER BY Data.id, Data.lastmodified, Data.createtimestamp, Goals.id, Actions.id
```

which creates the following error on the rsD.Open line:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Data.id = Goals.hapid INNER JOIN HAPActionSteps.csv AS Actions ON Goals.id = Actions.goali'with an error code of -2147217900

Can anyone see what's wrong with my SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if this is an Access-like syntax you need parentheses like this:

```
FROM (HAPData.csv AS Data INNER JOIN HAPGoals.csv ON Data.id = Goals.hapid)
           INNER JOIN HapActionSteps.csv AS Actions ON Goals.id = Actions.goalid
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks a lot!